# Completion Handler inside a loop?

Tags: swift, multithreading, swift3, queue

I have a method which receives an array of Messages. 
It checks whether the message contains a Media item or not and if it does contain a media item then it will check if the media is already cached on the device and if its not saved it will download the image and save it on the device.
at the end of each iteration, the media item or text will be shown in a collection view controller.

Everything works however they are not added in order which is absolutely normal, so I was wondering what I can do to overcome this issue?

```
This is how it should be shown 
------------------------------
Text
Picture -> not cached
Text
Text
Picture -> Cached
Text
Picture -> not cached


This is how it appears
----------------------
Text
Text
Text
Text
Picture -> Cached
Picture -> not cached
Picture -> not cached
```

*Update* My code is not really pretty at the moment :D

```
func singleSBDtoJSQ(messages:[SBDBaseMessage]) {
    print("sbmToJSQ")
    for message in messages {



        if let userMessage = message as? SBDUserMessage {

            let jsqMessage = CustomJSQMessage(senderId: userMessage.sender?.userId, senderDisplayName: userMessage.sender?.nickname, date: Date(ticks: UInt64(userMessage.createdAt)), text: userMessage.message)

            if userMessage.sender?.userId == self.senderId {
                jsqMessage?.status = " ✓✓ "
            }
            jsqMessage?.sbdBaseMessage = message

            self.messages.append(jsqMessage!)

        } else {


            let fileMessage = message as! SBDFileMessage
            print("file message")
            let url = URL(string: fileMessage.url)
            let cacheResult = ImageCache.default.isImageCached(forKey: (url?.absoluteString)!)

            if cacheResult.cached {
                ImageCache.default.retrieveImage(forKey: (url?.absoluteString)!, options: nil, completionHandler: { (image, cacheType) in
                    if let cachedImage = image as? UIImage {
                        let mediaItem = JSQPhotoMediaItem()
                        mediaItem.image = cachedImage
                        let jsqMessage = CustomJSQMessage(senderId: fileMessage.sender?.userId, displayName: fileMessage.sender?.nickname, media: mediaItem)

                        print("Image caches")

                        if fileMessage.sender?.userId == self.senderId {
                            jsqMessage?.status = " ✓✓ "
                            mediaItem.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = true
                        } else {
                            mediaItem.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = false
                        }

                        jsqMessage?.sbdBaseMessage = message

                        self.messages.append(jsqMessage!)
                        return


                    } else {
                        return
                    }

                })

            } else {
                print("image not cached")
                let imageView = UIImageView()
                imageView.kf.setImage(with: url, completionHandler: {
                    (image, error, cacheType, imageUrl) in

                    if error != nil {
                        print("error while downloading image")
                        return
                    } else {
                        print("image downloaded")
                        let mediaItem = JSQPhotoMediaItem()
                        mediaItem.image = image
                        let jsqMessage = CustomJSQMessage(senderId: fileMessage.sender?.userId, displayName: fileMessage.sender?.nickname, media: mediaItem)

                        if fileMessage.sender?.userId == self.senderId {
                            jsqMessage?.status = " ✓✓ "
                            mediaItem.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = true
                        } else {
                            mediaItem.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = false
                        }

                        jsqMessage?.sbdBaseMessage = message

                        self.messages.append(jsqMessage!)

                    }

                })

            }
        }
    }
    self.finishSendingMessage(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Could you add your code with the loop here? I think that you should use a dispatch group to make possible receive data before going to the next item in the loop

Comment: @Woof , I updated my answer with my code.  Im new to the whole Dispatch and threading but I will look into the Dispatch group . thank you for the comment

Comment: Rather than changing your code to force it to run in the correct order (which you can only accomplish by negatively impacting performance), it's often better to refactor so that the order that they complete does not matter. Common ways would be to update the results in some dictionary or approaches like that.

Comment: @Woof The Dispatch group solved my problem Thank you very much

Comment: @Rob Yes thats what I was thinking too. Would it be better to store them in a dictionary or keep them as they are and them sort them by using their timeStamp?